# Deserializing JSON with Newtonsoft with quotes in a value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am retrieving JSON from an API and have the following problem:
Some Json-values look like this and cannot be serialized the standard way

```
"key": "This is just a "dummy" value to show the problem",
```

The problem are the quotes around dummy. Newtonsoft obviously thinks the value ends with the quote before dummy, but it actually ends after problem.
Is there a way to ignore those quotes or somehow remove them automatically?

I've tried to remove them with a StringBuilder and String-Replace, but that didn't work because such a pattern occures mutliple times in the JSON-File and sometimes the nested quotes quote a single word, sometimes a whole sentence.

The whole JSON from the API has around 50.000 lines, so it's impossible to correct the error by hand.

Can this be solved somehow in C#?

Comment: thats not a valid JSON... to be more accurate I mean the quotes dont have escape sequence attached to them. Any quotes character inside a string should have them, otherwise its an invalid JSON.

Comment: Not unless you write a manual parser, thinking of all cases. Consider `"key": "This is just " broken"`, with only a single quote. How is any kind of general JSON parser supposed to divine the intent of the author there? You'd have to do ugly stuff like "well, let's assume a quote at the end of the line is the actual end". Madness leads down this path -- insist things be fixed on the producer end.

Comment: why don't you try encoding html before serializing

Comment: You should not try to build a workaround for an obviously trashy serializer, try to fix the serializer and escape the quotes.

Comment: The work you will have in order to fix this broken JSON will depend on your ability to detect patterns in the problems. If the only problem in the whole JSON follows a pattern that can match the json you showed you can easily create a simple parser to fix it.

Comment: Smells like "handmade" JSON - report an issue to the API provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: You have to write a custom parser to parse since its clearly not JSON then. What you have to do is fix the serialized object before you deseriliaze it. You have to iterate through the entire string and remove the unrequired quotes.

An example would be when the value property of a JSON ends and next one begins there is a **comma** character in the middle.

Its basically a huge nested if condition, to fix this.

**Original Answer**

[image: Your example]

As you can see, it does not parse as an valid JSON. You have to represent quotes as below. If its not someting in your control, you have to come up with a custom parser.

[image: Valid JSON with quotes]